# GC_FOR_ALLOC causing lag in Android game

Tags: android, garbage-collection, cocos2d-iphone

I am working on a cannon game for Android, which requires procedural generation of levels. As the player flies through the air, new sections get added on to the end of the level to keep it going indefinitely. As those sections are added, sections that the player has already passed are deleted. The problem is that the creation of a section usually leads to a GC_FOR_ALLOC, which pauses the game for around 30ms and causes noticeable lag.

The free memory stays fairly consistent, as objects are deleted while others are added, so there doesn't seem to be a memory leak.
The engine I am using is the cocos2D-android-1 port from iOS.

I saw many solutions along the lines of "don't initialize things while the game is running", but the nature of the level generation requires this, since an indefinite-length level can't be created right at the start of the game.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If too much garbage collection is occurring... then find a way to use less memory. I'm not sure what else you want us to say. There's no magic button to prevent the garbage collector from doing its job. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not very specific. If the lag is too big, you must try to reduce it.

One way could be to collect more often - resulting in shorter, but more often occurring  pauses.

For example you might create smaller or only partial sections and try to nudge the garbage collector afterwards to run. You would use `System.gc()` for this. But be aware that `System.gc()` is not guaranteed to result in it actually starting to run.

An even better solution would be to reuse objects. Objects that were created before the level was started. This way even an endless level would not result in any garbage collection since no garbage accumulates. But be sure to not create any non-pooled objects!

Comment: My apologies for not being specific enough. Thanks for the suggestion! I tried System.gc() under various circumstances (such as between section generation), but it didn't help very much. I am looking into implementing object pools now, since there will be large amounts of object reuse, and it is looking like a good solution.